# 2D integral over a function using dblquad where integrand depends on 2D array (shape (180*360)) and F(theta, phi)

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

```
    import astropy.io.fits as ap
    import numpy as np
    import  matplotlib 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
    from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
    import math
    from scipy.special import sph_harm
    from scipy.special import legendre
    import scipy.integrate

    def legendre(x,n):
     leg = legendre(n)
     P_n = leg(x)
     return P_n




    hdu1 = ap.open("magnetogram.fits")
    hdu1.info()  # so only one hdu list is there in this magnetogram fits file with 360X180
    data = hdu1[0].data
#print(data[0:, 359])  # the first run from 0 to 179 and other run from 0 to 359



    theta_old = np.arccos(np.linspace(-1, 1, num=180))
    theta_new = np.linspace(180*(3.14/180), 0, 180)

    Br_new = np.empty((180,360), float) #empty array of the same dimesnion as Br magnetogram

    for i in range(0, 360):
     f = interp1d(theta_old, data[0:, i], kind="cubic")
     Br_new[0:, i] = f(theta_new)

    Br_new = gaussian_filter(Br_new, sigma=[2, 2])

    print(data.shape, theta_old.shape)
    print(Br_new.shape)
    print(Br_new)

    plt.figure()
#x =  theta_old
#y = np.linspace(0, 360, 361)
#Z = data
#plt.imshow(Z, interpolation= "bilinear")
#plt.show()

    x_new = (np.linspace(3.14, 0, 181))
    y = np.linspace(0, 360, 361)
    Z = Br_new
    plt.imshow(Z, interpolation= "bilinear")
    plt.show()
    print("nnn")

    CmlCoefficients = []

    for l in range(0,3):
     #a = []
     for m in range(-l,l+1):
        freal = lambda Theta, Phi: Br_new[int(Theta), int(Phi)] * math.sin((3.14 / 180) * Theta) * 
               (np.real(
            scipy.special.sph_harm(-m, l, (3.14 / 180) * Phi, (3.14 / 180) * Theta)))  # legendre polynomial handle

        fimaginary = lambda Theta, Phi: Br_new[int(Theta), int(Phi)] * math.sin((3.14 / 180) * Theta) * 
               (np.imag(
            scipy.special.sph_harm(-m, l, (3.14 / 180) * Phi, (3.14 / 180) * Theta)))  # legendre 
         polynomial handle

        answerreal = (scipy.integrate.dblquad(freal, 0, 360, lambda Theta: 0, lambda Theta: 180))
        answerimag = (scipy.integrate.dblquad(fimaginary, 0, 360, lambda Theta: 0, lambda Theta: 180))
        CmlCoefficients.append((l, m, complex(answerreal[0], answerimag[0])))
        print(answerreal,answerimag)

        print(CmlCoefficients)
```

I am trying to integrate over a function F(theta, Phi) where the integrand depends on a 2D array of data of shape (180, 360) in product with some special mathematical function (spherical harmonics). Now the thing is my code works and evaluate the integrals for each value of l and m but the error in the integration is way too much. Say, for l=0 and m=0 value of the integral is -5113.672846048103 and error is 257.68725625979823

Is there any way to reduce the error??

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can compute integrals of low-degree spherical harmonics times a trig function on paper and pencil. Ok, maybe with a symbolic integrator like sympy.

Otherwise, do repeated one-dimensional integrals over tge angles using the `weights="sin"` parameter to `quad`. But I'm pretty sure paper-and-pencil will be less work here.